# Browser on host is started when starting it in a VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, libvirt

Here is my setup:

- My host system runs Ubuntu 18.04
- I have a VM (also running 18.04) using libvirt/KVM
- I connect to the VM using `ssh -X 1.2.3.4`

The weird thing is, if I run `firefox` in that SSH shell, a new browser window from my hosts's browser opens.

Which VM/Hypervisor magic is responsible for that behaviour?

And bonus question: How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

An answer has already been posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh

**TL;DR**: *X11 Shared Memory* is used when using SSH wit X-forwarding, `firefox --no-remote` prevents it.